# USB Dual Male Connector

Tags: pcb, usb, pcb-design, connector

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi Project and I want to integrate the Pi on a PCB. The Pi has a Dual Stack Female USB connector (Link for reference below). Now I need a similar Male Dual USB connector. I tried searching on the internet for such a connector but couldn't find. All I found was single Male USB connector(Image for reference below).
Using two usb cables could be a solution but I would like to avoid cables. Please help me find a part or give any solution to my problem. Thanks guys!

**USB Female Dual**
http://antenk01.en.made-in-china.com/offer/gqiJeowbXApl/Sell-USB-A-Female-Dual-Port.html

**USB Male Single**
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/437

Comment: Is it viable to create a PCB with 2 male headers in the right spacing?

Comment: Get a Model A and add the LAN9512 yourself.

Comment: A very unusual shopping question. You could possibly try to homebrew it by getting 2 exposed USB connectors and soldering wires from there to the PCB. I'm probably worried about how stable it would be and the disturbance of the data pins.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Raspberry Pi Compute Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/compute-module/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually quite an interesting design question hiding in here. You won't find a single connector part that will do what you want as it isn't a standard use case that would warrant mass production (i.e. nobody would make it because they wouldn't sell many).

The simplest way would be to build a PCB containing two USB A male connectors mounted in such a way that they will be in the right place. I can think of three ways this *might* be possible.

1. The first thought would be to get some SMD male connectors and mount one on each side of a PCB so that you get two connectors out the same side. However this would require to find just the right connectors - you would need two different connectors, which are basically the mirror image of each other (as one would be mounted on the reverse of the PCB. It would also require the PCB to be close enough to the right thickness to space the connectors.
2. An easier option would be to design a small PCB with one SMD USB connector on it, and have the second USB connector on your main PCB. The smaller board would plug in as a daughter board using some other connector such that the two USB male connectors are mounted above each other.
3. A third option would be to make a PCB which has two SMD USB connectors like [these ones](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/480372200_sd.pdf) mounted vertically as if they were through-hole parts. This should be possible as they have pins that stick out the middle, and metal edge tabs that could be soldered to pads on the PCB for support. You would need to design the board with the connectors at the right spacing to mate with the Pi, and then route the connections down through the PCB to a different connector which would allow the board to be connected to your main PCB vertically.

Comment: Okay Tom, First of all thanks for all the three ideas you suggested. I particularly found the third on to be the best way out. Using vertical USB connectors. This would require me 2 PCB's normal to each other. I will have to redesign the entire input output terminals if I go ahead with this. But this seems like the only systematic way out. Thanks alot mate!

Comment: Can you share with me the link to the product page.

Comment: @DevangSavla The part number of the linked connector is 48037-2200 - if you put that in google you get the molex page as well as ones from a few distributers.

Comment: I went the the product and the 3D design model they have. But its not actually a vertical mounting USB. Its a horizontal surface mounting connector. Also the metal shield has support at 90 degrees to the actual connector. This is not something I'm looking for.

Comment: @DevangSalva it's a surface mount one yesterday, but the legs could be fed though holes to mount it vertically with the metal tabs being then soldered on to pads on the connector side of the PCB. I've seen a product that did something similar with a connector like that. Either way if you are using a Pi then it is unlikely you are making a big commercial product, so hacks like this are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not seeing the connector you're looking for is simple - you're misusing USB connectors. They are designed to receive cables and small removable devices. Joining PCBs by only USB connectors will make the device you're building very sensitive to vibrations (this can be solved by providing additional mechanical connection, it's not clear whether you're planning to do this or not). Without additional support, simply sending your device to another city by regular mail will likely be fatal.

Also, using two USB ports instead of one will not give you any more bandwidth, since both ports are connected to the same hub. Connecting a single USB plug would be just as fast, so that's what I'd suggest to do.